Issue saving cookies while using express-sessions in MERN project
I am having a hard time saving the cookies on the client side of a MERN project. This is how the entry point of my server looks like:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const MongoDBSession = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

let PORT = process.env.NODE_PORT;

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
}).then(
    () => {
           console.log('Database is connected');
    },
    err => {
        console.log('Could not connect to the database. ' + err)
    });

const store = new MongoDBSession({
    uri: process.env.DB_URL,
    collection: 'sessions'
});

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        domain: '.frontend-domain.me',
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    },
    store: store
}));

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://frontend-domain.me',
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
    allowedHeaders: ['X-PINGOTHER', 'Content-Type'],
    credentials: true,
    maxAge: 86400
}));

// Some routes

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(404);
});
const server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log(`Server Connected on port #${PORT}. Restart Occured at ${new Date()}`);
    process.send('ready');
});

and my front end request that is used to set the session variable is like the following:
 axios.post('/route/to/my/server', {
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password

}, { withCredentials: true })
    .then(res => {
        // do something
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // handle
    });


to handle this request i have a file at my server that is:
router.post('/my/server', (req, res) => {
    // if the user is matched then:

    console.log("Logged in successfully");
    req.session.user = user;
    req.session.loggedin = true;
    req.session.save(function(err) {
        res.send({ 
            loggedin: true,
        });
    });
});

I have tried changing the cors settings, tries changing the cookies settings on the chrome, still no good response. After the response my cookies are not set: See image
and when i try to access the session variables in the next request, the session variables are not present there. Although session variables are stored in the Database. Also, i have two different subdomains for my frontend and backend, let them be frontend-domain.mydomain.me and backend-domain.mydomain.me. I have https enabled on both.

Hi, Can you please leave the field domain and try again. domain: '.frontend-domain.me'. The sameSite='none' should be suffice to handle it.

That did not work for me, what worked for me is that i did secure: false and sameSite: "Lax" and I dont know why this worked and not secure: true with  sameSite: "None" , because I have https configured on both frontend and backend

Hi, Who is your hosting provider ?

DigitalOcean is the provider

Hi, Some hosting providers put proxy in front of the express sever, and some others use other proxying mechanisms. Vercel uses rewrites not a proxy server. However Render uses proxy server. We had seen a case got fixed in render by setting trusting to the proxy. When express behind a proxy, there are certain API return values differently which you can read over here https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html. Therefore app.set('trust proxy', true) statement had become necessary in such cases.

...I am not sure about digitalOcean, if possible, please apply trust proxy and and try the same setup worked for you in the development.
